# JavaScript and subscribing to Events

Tags: javascript

I have something like this in a JavaScript control, how does one subscribe to this event?

```
if(typeof(pnlDialog.onclose) == 'function')
     pnlDialog.onclose();
```

I thought it was something like this, but haven't been successful.

```
var mycontrol = document.getElementById('myDialog');
mycontrol.attachEvent('onclose', function() 
{
         alert('closed');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's not using events at all, its just using a late bound function. Therefore use this:

```
var mycontrol = document.getElementById('myDialog');
mycontrol.onclose = function(){
  alert("Closed");
}
```

Comment: Technically, all functions in JavaScript are late-bound.

Answer (score 5):

.attachEvent is a microsoft-developed function, I think it pretty much only works in internet explorer.

Try .addEventListener, with this syntax:

```
var mycontrol = document.getElementById('myDialog');
mycontrol.addEventListener('onclose', function() 
{
     alert('closed');
}, false);
```

The "false" determines if the function should be executed in the capturing (true) or bubbling (false) phase. False should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see its really simple

```
var mycontrol = document.getElementById('myDialog'); 

mycontrol.onclose = function()  
{          
          alert('closed'); 
};
```